# Colocar nombre a imagen

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

Buenas tardes en mi app tomo una foto con la cámara y seguidamente la guardo en el álbum de fotos de la cámara, pero me la guarda con un nombre por default me gustaría saber como colocarle el nombre que yo quiera a la foto, el código que tengo a la hora de guardar la imagen es el siguiente:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

        self.guardaImagen = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.guardaImagen!, nil, nil, nil);

        self.imagePick.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("envioFotoLink", sender: self)
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No es posible utilizando el método `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` ya que la imagen se guarda en el carrete. Es la forma que tiene el sistema de evitar duplicados en el nombre del fichero, mantener una sincronización correcta, etc.

Para más info [UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum)

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 1**

Añado código para guardar imagen en la carpeta `Documents`

```
// Carpeta Documents
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

// Nombre imagen
let imageName = "imagen.png"

// Imagen y imagen en formato NSData
if let image = UIImage(named: "image"), let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {

    // Creamos la URL final
    let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath).URLByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)

    do {

        // Guardamos imagen
        try imageData.writeToURL(filePath, options: [])

    } catch {

        print(error)

    }

}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41039/discussion-on-answer-by-mhergon-colocar-nombre-a-imagen).